# Ubuntu terminal shortcut for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

Does anyone know Ubuntu shortcut to install latest ruby on rails framework?

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421, along with "[ask]". We'd like to see some evidence of your effort in researching this, and why that research didn't help.

Comment: Without knowing much about Ruby, I would imaging installing gem first, then gem installing rails... But read the link @theTinMan gave!

Comment: You *can* use the built-in `yum` or `apt-get` with \*nix but in general you really want to use [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) as a sandbox manager. They're not compatible so pick one or the other. RVM is very full-featured but more complex. In either case, they'll install Ruby into your home directory, making it easy to install and manage Rubies and their associated gems *without ever needing to use `sudo`*. `apt-get` and `yum` tend to lag behind the current Rubies but RVM and rbenv closely track the bleeding-edge

Comment: I apologize guys.  won't happen again (new to this obviously).  Thanks Tin Man.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Ruby is installed by default, so you just want to do:</strike>

```
# Install Ruby
sudo apt-get install ruby

# Install rails gem
sudo gem install rails
```

But, I would suggest using `rvm` or `rbenv` to manage your ruby versions and gemsets.

Comment: _Ruby is installed by default_ in Ubuntu?

Comment: I have recently read somewhere that 16.04 comes prepackaged with `ruby 2.3`. But, I a quick google search is not yielding any results. I always thought Ubuntu desktop comes with system installed ruby, just like OSX, no?! I don't have my hands on clean Ubuntu machine. You got me intrigued... got to find a spare vm for a quick test now :)

Comment: @Uzbekjon It depends on what options you pick during install and if you're using Server or Desktop. In any case, `apt-get install ruby` fixes it.